# what's the meaning of "Something is sure to do something"

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does "is sure to abet" mean in this sentence?

> The photo editing software is sure to abet my odds of winning the photo competition.

Could you give me more examples having the phrase "something is sure to do something" ?

Comment: It means "help."  In this case "increase" would be a good substitution. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abet

Comment: @MaxW so thanks alot, and please post it as the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Is sure to" is equivalent to "is definitely going to."  For example,

> The photo editing software **is sure to** abet my odds of winning the photo competition.

means

> The photo editing software **is definitely going to** abet my odds of winning the photo competition.

Here are some more examples:

> ### He is sure to get the job.
>
> He is definitely going to get the job; it is certain that he will get the job.
>
> ### Clinton is sure to win the nomination.
>
> Clinton is definitely going to win the nomination; it is certain that Clinton will win the nomination.

If you still don't understand it, please tell me.

Comment: so in here abet doesn't mean encourage but increased, right?

Comment: Actually my question was the meaning of the whole **is sure to abet**

Comment: The word "abet" is not really being used correctly here; it means to encourage a crime or wrongdoing.  However, that aside, the sentence can loosely be rephrased as "the photo editing software is sure to increase my odds of winning the photo competition.

Comment: A nice one-word substitution for _is sure to_ is _will_; perhaps a more accurate two-word substitution is _will surely_. For example; _He will surely get the job; Clinton will surely win the nomination._ As for _is sure to abet_, that simply means "will surely help," since "abet" means "to help", but it's not a very commonly used word. Also, although [the OP didn't make this sentence up](http://wordsinasentence.com/abet-in-a-sentence/), I don't think it's a very good example sentence. Google returns a great number of hits for `the software will help`, but just one for `the software will abet`.

Comment: @J.R. That's true.  I just didn't want to use "surely" because then I'm not explaining what "sure" means.

Comment: ostrich - Good point. Maybe I should have used _certainly_.

Comment: @J.R. That works.

Comment: The answer could be improved, imho,  by including in it the  information on the meaning and (mis)use of *abet*. That info seems critical to know for a learner interested in using the word.